# I need to get the numeric type columns from a table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I need to create some SQL scripts in real-time using data held in lists. I do this using some hardcode text and format strings and a string builder. So far this works but I have experienced a problem as my code always puts single quotes around the values to insert. If the field is a non-numeric type then this fails as I need to create the value without the quotes. As some text fields also use numbers I can’t parse the values in the list. My plan is to run something like the following to get the column details for a given table.

```
EXEC sp_columns tablename
```

I have created a dictionary from this output of COLUMN_NAME and TYPE_NAME in c#. This isn’t ideal as I still have to do a bit of parsing to see if the type is numeric. What I would like to do is run a query that just returns the COLUMN_NAME if the type is numeric (int, float, real etc). My c# code can then just check the list to see if the field I am currently working on exists. If it does I don’t quote the value. Can anyone advise on a query I could run that will could do this?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Look for Connection.GetSchema()

Answer (score 2):

The information schema contains all this information, so this query would work:

```
SELECT [COLUMN_NAME],[DATA_TYPE] FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] 
WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = 'Table_1' AND [NUMERIC_PRECISION] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This  doesn’t work as it doesn’t select field types such as “int” which are numeric.

Comment: OK, no worries, I have amended the query.  I thought you were after columns that were just the numeric type, not all number type columns.

Comment: I have edited my original question to indicate what I meant by “numeric”. I have tried you revised code and it appears to do what I need. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use simple and straightforward solution:

```
var query = "your query here";
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString))
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    da.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Mapped);
    da.Fill(table);
}
```